# Opening image asset Java JDK 8

Tags: java, image, path, java-8, assets

I am attempting to load an image called Default.png stored within the project and draw it onto a canvas. I am well aware of ImageIO.read however no matter what path I give it, I can't seem to load it. Where should I put the image? I have tried putting it in a separate folder calles "res," putting it into assets.author.mypackagename.textures, but no matter what I do I cannot seem to find the right location and how to access it. Any help is appreciated, comment for further specifics.

Comment: What is the package structure where you have your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have it in a separate folder called `res` you can load the image by doing this:

`ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/Default.png"));`

you can also do something like:

`ImageIO.read(new File("res/Default.png"));`

The second method doesn't need the picture to be in another folder, but for me it's cleaner that way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the resources are loaded in the classpath relative to the current package. If `/com/daniel/project/src/` is in your classpath, and images are in `/com/daniel/project/src/image` then use:

```
ImageIO.read( ClassLoader.getSystemResource( "image/Default.png" ) );
```

But the `src` folder is not included in the classpath by IDEs generally. Try adding the image to the `bin` folder.

Comment: So just to be clear, the place to put it would be com.daniel.project.src.image. Thanks, i'll try it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you are using Android Studio and that you are attempting to change your application's icon image.  If that is the case, the documented way of making the change is via Android Studio's Image Asset Studio, and the way to opening is:

In Android Studio, do File --> Open

Then choose your project's Android folder, and select to open it in a new window.

Wait something like 45 seconds for all the data to come in, and then after that right click on the 'res' folder, and you shall then see the option to open the image asset studio.